# Swift: Precondition error on device but not emulator?

Tags: swift, swiftui

For some reason I am receiving

> precondition failure: attribute failed to set an initial value: 98

When running an application on my real iPhone device, but not in the emulator.

This is the initial view that runs:

```
 import SwiftUI

    struct NavBar: View {
        var body: some View {
            TabView {
                View0()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                        Text("view1")
                    }.tag(0)
                View1()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "cart")
                        Text("view1")
                    }.tag(1)
                View2()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
                        Text("view2")
                }.tag(2)
            }
        }
    }
```

The precondition failure pops up when I switch from View0 to View1.

View0:

```
import SwiftUI

struct View0: View {

    var favorites: [String]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Image(systemName: "photo")
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Simon ng")
            }
            Text("test phrase")
            Text("blah blah")
        }
    }
}
```

View1:

```
import SwiftUI

struct View1: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("test")
    }
}
```

How should I go about debugging this?

Comment: What versions of iOS are you running on the device and emulator?

Comment: The only thing I see here... try to comment `favorites` or initialize it `var favorites: [String] = []`

Comment: @simibac I am running iOS version 13.3 on an iPhone 8 emulator. My test device is an iPhone XR.

Comment: I'm also facing this issue only when I switch the tabs very fast, but on real device iPhone XR. Not seeing the issue on real device iPhone XR. SwiftUI is really weird.

Comment: @MohamedWasiq I found a solution. Check my answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue.

Within each of the views in my TabView (i.e. View0, View1, View2) I went back and made sure to wrap each List in a NavigationView.

i.e. for View0's body:

```
var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
        List {
            Image(systemName: "photo")
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Simon ng")
            }
            Text("test phrase")
            Text("blah blah")
        }
    }
}
```